# Sharepoint Online Modern script editor webpart(spfx) is not available in some sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have build and deployed the react-script-editor web part to app catalog as explained on site(https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor). It is available in one of the site and not available on other sites.

Comment: could you check the differences between the working site and non-working sites? Are they all Modern sites?

Comment: Both are Modern sites only.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your solution to be available across the tenant if not check the following article :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-scoped-deployment

Comment: We do not want it on all the modern sites so we have selected skipFeatureDeployment  as false. Let us know if this is the issue.

Comment: "skipFeatureDeployment" is responsible for making the solution available to all sites in your organization, so set skipFeatureDeployment to "true" and bundle your solution and package it then make sure you check "Make  this solution available to all sites in the organization" when the popup shows up.

Comment: Give some context in the answer from the link, link only answer may be useless if its broken in future.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the difference is between Team and Communication sites.  Team sites were fine. 
 Tried following some other recommendations and maybe some helped, but at the end of the day, did this on my Communication site:

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity "https://<URL>" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```